# Opening documents results in security warning

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, download, warning

I am a sharepoint beginner but help run our company site, and on it we have a resource library full of several libraries with urls to documents and files. We suddenly came upon an issue where clicking these files results in a security warning before downloading the file. Up to yesterday, clicking the urls of the file would open it as a new page in the browser, which is what I want the site to keep doing. This issue is happening on all of the browsers I've tested it on (chrome and edge).

This issue appears to be only happening on our main resource library site, as other sites with libraries are still opening documents fine in the browser without a warning.

The only recent change made to the library came from adjusting all of the views' column formatting to make it so that the titles would wrap the text and be one click links, rather than needing a double click. The JSON code for this change is as follows:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "customRowAction": {
    "action": "defaultClick"
  },
  "style": {
    "white-space": "wrap",
    "cursor": "pointer"
  },
  "txtContent": "@currentField"
}
```

I'm not sure if the issue is related to an MS Office update or if it is from making some adjustment to the sharepoint site, but any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Please following steps:**

1.Start >> Run >> **gpedit.msc** >> Enter

2.On the Local Group Policy Editor, click on **Computer Configuration** >> **Administrative Templates** >> **Windows Components** >> **Internet Explorer** >> Enable "**Turn Off the security settings check feature**" option

[image]

3.On the Local Group Policy Editor, click on **User Configuration** >> **Administrative Templates** >> **Windows Components** >> **Internet Explorer** >> Enable "**Turn Off the security settings check feature**" option

[image]

4.Restart the computer